# Disable prefix in model name while swagger client generation

Tags: go, templates, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am very new to Golang, trying to generate client code in golang

My swagger file has model name as models.BaseModel but the client code contains name as **models.ModelsBaseModel**

I want to avoid this prefix Models and want the model name as **models.BaseModel** instead of **models.ModelsBaseModel**

I am using swagger generate client command with the below template
https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/blob/master/generator/templates/client/response.gotmpl

```
  Payload {{ if and (not .Schema.IsBaseType) (not .Schema.IsInterface) .Schema.IsComplexObject (not .Schema.IsStream) }}*{{ end }}{{ if (not .Schema.IsStream) }}{{.Schema.GoType}}{{ else }}io.Writer{{end}}
```

In the above code, ***{{.Schema.GoType}}*** is the parameter which is generating the model name.
Its value is ***models.ModelsBaseResponse**

***Note:***

I have already tried stripPackage functions (https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) and other string functions like replace, trimPrefix, etc but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

{{.Schema.GoType | replace "Models" ""}}
This solved the problem